# Can anybody advise how to improve this question?

Tags: support, quality

I made this:

[When making an offer, can HR override a successful set of interviews with senior management?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/154340/when-making-an-offer-can-hr-override-a-successful-set-of-interviews-with-senior)

but I am quite unhappy with the result. The situation is "interviews for a big job went very well, now HR is all doubtful and wants me to justify myself". I am trying to understand if it's a tactic, if it's common, or if it's a red flag. But maybe there is a better way of asking this. Any help is very much welcome.

Comment: I wanted to improve my question, the answer was pretty good already

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked for ideas to improve it, I will make a few suggestions. Take these as what they are, simply my opinion:

- Edit your text such that your title actually matches your question (right now the title is asking *"can they do this"* but the body is asking *"what should I do, now that they've done this"*)
- Avoid "What should I do" as a question. Or, at least, if you must ask what to do, make sure you have clearly stated your goal(s), what you've already tried or are considering trying, and other context.
- Don't immediately accept an answer, especially if the question is less than a few days old and/or only has one answer - an accepted answer is often interpreted as a flag that you are satisfied (and maybe even that you've abandoned the question and don't care about it any more).

Answer (score 0):

Question looks well enough to me, and you've had what looks to be a great answer from SZCZERZO KŁY